# Sql joining a table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a question regarding the SQL joins -

Whenever we join two different tables on some fields, what will happen exactly inside oracle which will result in the query output?

Does Oracle create/use a temporary table *just* for presenting the query output?

Answer (score 4):

There is an [overview](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/optimops.htm#39473) of join mechanisms used in Oracle and a couple of [Oracle wiki](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Join) pages about [join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Join):

- [Cluster join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Cluster_join)
- [Hash join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Hash_join)
- [Nested loops join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Nested_loops_join)
- [Sort merge join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Sort_merge_join)

Answer (score 1):

The Cost-based optimizer documentation gives plenty of detail pertaining to access paths, how blocks of data are read, which scans are used etc.etc.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/optimops.htm#35891

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be temporary table, I guess it will table in the memory to speed up the operation.

Answer (score 0):

If by "temporary table" you mean an Oracle global temporary table (GTT), the answer is No, Oracle never uses a GTT *just for presenting* the query output, but on the other hand, Yes, it *might* use a GTT for storing intermediate results depending on the query plan.